# Unity WebGL audio issue on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

Im having trouble with the audio on my game. It plays normally on other browsers but on chrome the build plays but without sound. [The sound playing icon apears, but with no sound.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJOb6.png)

Ive already tried changing the audio format (from mp3 to ogg) and even changing my Unity version (from 2020.3.30f1 to 2021.2.17f1).

Comment: Mine work on chrome. So it would suggest something slightly funky

Comment: Does anything appear in the Chrome console? Chrome prevents you from playing audio in a tab until the user interacts with the page, to prevent spammy sound effects.

That, or another reason might prevent audio from playing in Chrome specifically.